# No Logs created in Odoo 8

Tags: logging, odoo

I m trying to log in Odoo 8 in a click but there is no result below is my code

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class sample(models.Model):
    @api.one
    def test(self):
        _logger.info("Logging")
```

but i m unable to get any logs. Can anyone pls help me out with this? I m quite new to Odoo 8

Answer (score 0):

Logging is defined either by your startup script or your `.openerp_serverrc` or `.odoorc` file (odoo10 uses .odoorc) unless you have specified an alternate config file. To determine why you are getting no logging.

1. Check your startup script (if a config file is defined here it will
   be used.
2. Check the above mentioned files

Once you find your active config file look for the following settings

- `log_handler`
- `log_level`
- `logfile`
- `logrotate`

For your above example you will probably want

```
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
logrotate = True
```

Now assuming the permissions are correct in your logfile path (and your script is running at all) you should find logging in `/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log`. The example assumes a linux environment. If you prefer to set your logging parameters in your startup script you can do this as well. The syntax is a little different.

```
`/path/to/odoo.py` --logfile /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log --logrotate  --log-handler :INFO --log-level info`
```

Review the [Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html) for further information regarding configuration parameters and startup options.

Comment: But i want a custom log file how can I do that?? Actually i did something but it didn't create any log file 'logging.basicConfig(filename= /home/mukul/logger.log, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filemode= 'w', level= logging.INFO)'  @phillipstack